# The redirect_uri URL must be absolute facebook Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I want to make login with facebook using Socialite in laravel. First I set the route function:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::get('auth/facebook', [
       'as' => 'auth-facebook',
       'uses' => 'usersController@redirectToProvider'
    ]);

     Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', [
       'as' => 'facebook-callback',
       'uses' => 'usersController@handleProviderCallBack'
    ]);

});
```

And then I make function in the user controller:

```
public function redirectToProvider(){
       return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
   }
```

But I'm getting the error `The redirect_uri URL must be absolute`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you configure Socialite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the configuration.

You will also need to add credentials for the OAuth services your application utilizes. These credentials should be placed in your `config/services.php` configuration file, and should use the key `facebook`, `twitter`, `linkedin`, `google`, `github` or `bitbucket`, depending on the providers your application requires. For example:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '',
    'client_secret' => '',
    'redirect' => '',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Add callbackURL along with clientID and clientSecret
fb": {
        "clientID": "*************************",
        "clientSecret": "*******************************",
        "callbackURL": "//************/auth/facebook/callback",
        "profileFields": ["id", "displayName", "photos"]
    },