# Object not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

As I already ask about [The redirect_uri URL must be absolute facebook Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589097/the-redirect-uri-url-must-be-absolute-facebook-laravel) now I have another error connected with this problem. After I fix the redirect uri, now I have problem with the callback function.

First time I can login with facebook but then I have error Object now found. I' dont know hot to set the redirect parameter.

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'here is code',
        'client_secret' => 'here is code',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8080/code/task1/auth/callback',
    ],
```

Comment: do you have route to the callback function?

Comment: `Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'FacebookController@handleProviderCallback');`

Comment: so you're missing /facebook. `localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback`

Comment: I try with that and again i have the same error

Comment: the error is with the url. make sure the url (showing object not found) is in the route that uses callback function.

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: @epowah You could check it by adding `Log::info('This is my Foobar  callback')` into your code and then check `storage/logs/laravel.log`to see if the line `This is my Foobar  callback` is present (i.e. if the code was executed)